# Is it possible to make an overlay on a specific window with any python GUI library

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, overlay

I am making an app lock - type overlay on discord so that whenever it becomes the active window, the overlay should appear, I type password and the overlay disappears.
It is possible to do that with any python GUI library?
If yes, then How?

Also, is there any windows feature or software to do that?